# Finding all placements in a grid for certain polyomino

Tags: java, python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

How would I find all possible placements of a certain polyomino within a grid? For example,
just looking at the T tetromino **without transformations** (excuse the MS paint skills): [image]What is the *fastest* way to figure out how many ways I can place that tetromino on the just a rectangular grid like the first grid? Would there have to be a different method for irregular grids like Grid 2? Is the only way to brute force it by just placing it on every cell and seeing if all of the tetromino is within bounds?

Comment: For the first grid, the T-tetromino in the orientation you show can fit in 42 places: the top-left cell can go in any column other than the rightmost and in any row other than the two at the bottom, and that determines where the rest of it goes.  Similarly for any other rectangular grid.  As for grids such as the second, without knowing anything about the irregularity of the grid there isn't anything you can do other than check all the locations and see where the polyomino fits.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I assume OP is looking for something like a 2D version of [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)